# Less fps in loading screen of my android app

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

`I have written this code for loading screen of my android app.
But whenever i install it on my phone the fps of my loading screen is very low seems like it has 2-3 fps
The loading screen is a gif file.

```
class splash_screen:AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)
        val gifImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.loading_gif)
        Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.drawable.loading_gif).into(gifImageView)
        val background = object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000)
                    val intent = Intent(baseContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        background.start()
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use coroutine instead of regular thread.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
  delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
  withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { startActivity(Intent(baseContext, MainActivity::class.java)) }
}
```

Dont forget to add coroutines to your dependencies in your app's build.gradle

```
dependencies { 
 implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9")
}
```

You can read more about them here: [https://reflectoring.io/understanding-kotlin-coroutines-tutorial/#:~:text=Coroutines%20are%20more%20efficient%20than,for%20the%20coroutines%20to%20complete](https://reflectoring.io/understanding-kotlin-coroutines-tutorial/#:%7E:text=Coroutines%20are%20more%20efficient%20than,for%20the%20coroutines%20to%20complete).